# os.makedirs が実際にディレクトリを作成するまで時間がかかる

Tags: python, python2

海外サイトも含め検索しましたが、有効な解決策を見つけることができませんでした。
お知恵をお貸し頂けないでしょうか。
OS：Windows

os.makedirs()を使いディレクトリを作成した際、実際にディレクトリが作成されるまでに”少々”の時間がかかります。
後続処理では当然ながらos.path.isdir()を使ってディレクトリが生成済みであるかどうかを確認したうえでファイル転送を行うようにしていますが、
PCスペックによりますが約50%の確率でディレクトリ生成より前に処理が進んでしまいチェックの網にかかってしまいます。

暫定処置としてos.makedirsの直後にtime.sleep(2)を埋め込んで時間をおいてから後続処理に進むようにしたところ表面的には解決しましたが、根本的には解決されていません。

そこで、ディレクトリの作成が終わったかどうか、もしくは、正常終了したのかどうかを何らかの戻り値で確認する方法はありますでしょうか。
また、os.makedirsに限らず、スクリプトの処理とは別にOS側作業に時間がかかるような処理について戻り値を受け取ってから後続処理に進むような判定はできますでしょうか。

ディレクトリ生成はローカルとFTP先と両方で行っています。もしお分かりでしたら、ftplib.FTPで接続している場合のFTP接続先(いずれもWindowsPC同士)である場合に、ディレクトリ生成終了ステータスなどを拾える手段があるかについても教えて頂けないでしょうか。

【追記】
コメントを頂きありがとうございます。ソースコードは以下のとおりです。

```
try:
    if os.path.isdir(self.aaa):
        shutil.rmtree(self.aaa)
    os.makedirs(self.aaa)
    time.sleep(2)
except Exception as e:
    print e
try:
    if os.path.isdir(self.aaa):
        # ファイルコピー処理
     else:
        logger.info(u"まだ生成できていないです")
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Comment: 現象を再現するコードの提示は可能でしょうか。

Comment: os.makedirsが返った時ディレクトリが作成できていないというのが不思議です。どういう環境ですか? またmakedirsは内部でmakedirs自身を呼んでいます。それが戻った時ディレクトリ作成できていない環境は想定していないので、そのような環境ではmakedirsの正常動作も期待できません(makedirsの定義はos.pyにあります) [※先のコメントが修正できなくなったので消して書き直しました]

Comment: コメントを頂きありがとうございます。コメント欄ですと改行ができないらしいので本文に追記いたしました。特に煩雑な処理は書いていないのでどうしたものかと悩んでおります。

Answer (score 2):

os.makedirsが返った時ディレクトリがキャッシュにしかできていない可能性があります。

このケースでは、直前に削除を行っていますが、大量のデータの削除をしていませんか。その場合、キャッシュの処理は終わり戻り値が帰ってきているが、ディスク本体の処理が終わっていないという状態になります。書き込みをしようするディレクトリー名が削除しているディレクトリー名が同じなので、削除処理が完了しないと処理が競合してしまのでエラーが発生することは十分考えられます。

とりあえず削除でなくて、ディレクトリー名の変更にしておいて、後で削除したらどうでしょうか。renameの処理は高速です。

```
try:
    if os.path.isdir(self.aaa):
       os.rmname(self.aaa, self.aaa + '_bak')
    os.makedirs(self.aaa)
except Exception as e:
    print e

try:
    # ファイルコピー処理
except Exception as e:
    print e

if os.path.isdir(self.aaa + '_bak'):
    shutil.rmtree(self.aaa + '_bak')
```

Comment: ご回答くださいましてありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおりでした。確かにディレクトリ名が同一で、ファイルごと一括削除のためその処理に時間がかかりタイムラグが生じているようです。原因が分かり気持ちがすっきりしました。削除と生成の仕様を変更することにいたします。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: @YasuhiroNiji Windows kernel 内でキャッシュの処理が終わったなら、それで削除は完了です。
ディスク上にいつ反映されるかはアプリケーションの関知することではありません。
削除が終わったはずなのに、その後に作ったディレクトリがディスクの反映に巻き込まれて消えてしまうなど、あるはずがありません。
質問者さんの場合は解決したようですが、別の理由でたまたま回避できた、と考えるべきだと思います。

Comment: これと同じ経験したことあります。

Comment: os.path.isdirの処理をキャッシュだけで処理せずディスク側とやり取りするとこのような結果になっておかしいことではありません。どこまでキャッシュだけでするかは設定にもよります。

Comment: 「キャッシュだけで処理せずディスク側とやり取りするとこのような結果になっておかしいことではありません」なので、ディスク側と直接やりとりするはずがないという認識です。ですが、質問者さんと @YasuhiroNiji さんが同じ症状に遭遇し、同じ方法で解決したとのことなので、私も試してみたいと思います。「どこまでキャッシュだけでするかは設定にもよります」この設定がどこにあるのか教えていただけませんか?

Comment: linuxの場合は/etc/sysctl.confにキャッシュ関係の設定をするところがあります。

Comment: @YasuhiroNiji ありがとうございます。Linux でも同様の問題が再現できるということですか?

Comment: 遅いHDDを使うと再現しやすいです。書き込みキャシュをするかどうかというのは、電源断のときにデータをなくしてもいいかどうかという問題になるので設定は必ずあると思います。

Answer (score 0):

Windowsの環境が手元になくLinuxで試してみましたが、下記の通りディレクトリが作成されるタイムラグは出ませんでした。

このコードを該当の環境で試して結果をお知らせ下さい。

```
$ cat sample.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import shutil

fname = "aaa"
fpath = os.getcwd() + os.path.sep + fname

try:
    if os.path.isdir(fpath):
        shutil.rmtree(fpath)
    os.makedirs(fpath)
    print os.path.isdir(fpath)
except Exception as e:
    print e
$ python sample.py 
True
$ python sample.py 
True
$ python sample.py 
True
$ python sample.py 
True
$ python sample.py 
True
$
```

pythonのバージョンは下記の通りです。

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.4
$
```

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおり正しく表示されました。実行環境はテスト環境のためEclipseのデバッグモードです。今回は確かに再現しませんでしたが、昨日は現象を連発していたので「そのような現象は起こりえない仕様」ということですと納得いかない感じもいたします。

Comment: 確認ありがとうございました。再現した時に、もう一度、同じプログラムを実行すると何かわかるかもしれませんね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今しがた再現していたのですが、原因が判明いたしました。Yasuhiro Niji様のご指摘どおりディレクトリをファイル毎一括削除直後に同一名称で生成していることに起因しているようです。仕様変更で対応いたします。ご回答くださいまして誠にありがとうとざいました。